# How do I make Date Properties in Java?

Tags: c#, java, date

Working with C#, I can go inside classes and make properties like this:

```
 public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

I know that in Java I can forget the whole automatic get, set thing, but how do I make a DateTime of sorts in Java?

Comment: You may also want to look at [Joda-Time project](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 1):

Date is largely deprecated, you want [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

The "automatic get, set thing" are properties. Java doesn't have this (and it's not relevant to your question as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

The class you want is java.util.Date.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 0):

In Java the equivalent of `DateTime` is `Date`. You would need a getter/setter and a backing field, like this:

```
private Date m_date;

public Date getDate() {
    return m_date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    m_date = date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the good Java date functionality is found in the `GregorianCalendar` class, and you can make one of these by writing

```
Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and just using it via the `Calendar` interface.  Don't bother looking at the `Date` class, as it's really just a wrapper for a `long`, and all the date-related functionality in it has been deprecated.

The Calendar class has various `set` methods which you can use to set the value once you've created one.  There's a big long list on the Javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html.

One trap for beginners - when you set the month with an integer, the range of values is 0 to 11, not 1 to 12.  In other words, January is month 0.